# Can I realistically avoid Routing Attributes in WebAPI?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Lets say I have a domain like this...

```
ServiceType
  One - Process
    Many - Version
      Many  - Sections
        Many  - Questions
```

And I want to get a list of Versions for a ServiceType.

If I stick to the RESTful verbs I am going to have to get the service type.

From here I have two options,

1) my returned viewmodel has eagerly loaded viewmodels for process and then versions.

2) my returned viewmodel just has an id for Process which I then look up and then this will return ids for the Versions which again I can look up again by id.

At the moment I don't feel like either of these options fit.

Option 1 means that whenever i get a ServiceType by id I am going to get a load of others things I might not want.
Option 2 means many more requests as I get the id only to requery the api for the next thing I need.

Both of these options are also going to be exponentially worse if for some reason I ever wanted to get questions for a ServiceType.

I believe i am going to abandon (in this case) the verbs and create a new method on the version controller called GetVersionsByServiceTypeId. I can then marry this up using the RoutingAttributes.

This will work, but I am worried that I am going down a slippery slope of not going full RESTful which will cause problems or code smells down the line.

Am I going about this wrong?